# Проблема с вызовом функции в AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.when('/startPage', {
                    controller: 'StartPageController',
                    templateUrl: 'views/startPage.view.html',
                    resolve: {
                        loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                name: 'CemeteryApp',
                                files: [
                                    'scripts/controllers/startPage.controller.js',
                                    'scripts/controllers/modals/signIn.modal.controller.js',
                                    'scripts/services/mainService.js'
                                ]
                            })
                        }
                    }
                })



$scope.CreateNewUser = function () {
                MainService.CreateUser($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password, OnCreateUserCallback);
            }

service.CreateUser = function (email, password, callback) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: config.API_SERVER + '/CreateUser',
                        data: {
                            email: email,
                            password: password
                        }
                    }).then(function (response) {
                            callback(response);
                        }, function (response) {
                            callback(response);
                        }
                    );
                };
```

Работаю над созданием метода для добавления новых пользователей. Код работал и новые записи добавлялись в базу однако после повторного теста через некоторое время выбрасывает следующую ошибку.

```
angular.js:14642 TypeError: MainService.CreateUser is not a function
    at ChildScope.$scope.CreateNewUser (signIn.modal.controller.js:48)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15500), <anonymous>:4:159)
    at callback (angular.js:27285)
    at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:18372)
    at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18472)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:27290)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

UPDATE

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('CemeteryApp')
    .controller('StartPageController', ['$scope', 'MainService', '$location', '$window', '$uibModal',
        function ($scope, MainService, $location, $window, $uibModal) {

            $scope.loadSignInModal = function (obj) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'views/modals/signIn.modal.html',
                    controller: 'SignInController',
                    backdrop: 'dynamic',
                    closable: true,
                    resolve: {
                        currOrganization: function () {
                            return obj;
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

// ---------------------- Callbacks ----------------------- //


// --------------------- Get data ------------------------- //


        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что `MainService` в момент вызова не существует, по причине, того, что его не инжектировали. Это возможная причина. Для более точного ответа, нужен код контроллера

Comment: Обновил вопрос с кодом контроллера)

Comment: А код контроллера ```SignInController```? Вы в этот контроллер инжектировали ```MainService```?

Comment: angular.module('CemeteryApp')
    .controller('SignInController', ['$scope', 'MainService', '$window', '$uibModal', '$uibModalInstance', '$location',
        function ($scope, MainService, $window, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, $location) {

Comment: проблема была в MainService я инжектировал его в конце)